# What does the type parameter in front of method do if not using it as parameter?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

If we have an abstract method

```
public abstract class Test {
  public abstract <T> void method();
}
```

then all concrete derived classes are forced to have `<T>` in their method signature:

```
public class Test1 extends Test {
    public <T> void method() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

What is the use case of this? What can we do with `T`? And how does `T` get its inference from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation it is no reason to have generic parameter, but java specification do not forbid it.

Someone who did that just made mistake.

**EDIT**

PS: I found the case when generic parameter is not in method signature, but still useful. (Thanks to @JimmyB for idea)

Imagine that you have two interfaces:

```
interface A {}

interface B {}
```

Also two methods with next signatures:

```
<T extends A & B> T f1();

<T extends A & B> void f2(T t);
```

Then you can have method like this:

```
<T extends A & B> void foo() {
    T t = f1();
    f2(t);
}
```

It is not exactly method in question because it have constraints on generic parameter, but it is as close as I can get.

Comment: Notice that the type parameter can still be used inside the method to more or less ensure multiple local variables have the same apparent type.

Comment: Hummm, not too sure if this is the correct answer. But there is no better one than this.

Comment: @JimmyB yes, but it is useless because you can always identify their type. Also you can't assign to those vars :)